# How to efficiently use Rprof in R?

Tags: r, profiling, profiler

I would like to know if it is possible to get a profile from `R`-Code in a way that is similar to `matlab`'s Profiler. That is, to get to know which line numbers are the one's that are especially slow.

What I acchieved so far is somehow not satisfactory. I used `Rprof` to make me a profile file. Using `summaryRprof` I get something like the following:

> ```
> $by.self
>                   self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
> [.data.frame               0.72     10.1       1.84      25.8
> inherits                   0.50      7.0       1.10      15.4
> data.frame                 0.48      6.7       4.86      68.3
> unique.default             0.44      6.2       0.48       6.7
> deparse                    0.36      5.1       1.18      16.6
> rbind                      0.30      4.2       2.22      31.2
> match                      0.28      3.9       1.38      19.4
> [<-.factor                 0.28      3.9       0.56       7.9
> levels                     0.26      3.7       0.34       4.8
> NextMethod                 0.22      3.1       0.82      11.5
> ...
> ```

and

> ```
> $by.total
>                       total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
> data.frame                  4.86      68.3      0.48      6.7
> rbind                       2.22      31.2      0.30      4.2
> do.call                     2.22      31.2      0.00      0.0
> [                           1.98      27.8      0.16      2.2
> [.data.frame                1.84      25.8      0.72     10.1
> match                       1.38      19.4      0.28      3.9
> %in%                        1.26      17.7      0.14      2.0
> is.factor                   1.20      16.9      0.10      1.4
> deparse                     1.18      16.6      0.36      5.1
> ...
> ```

To be honest, from this output I don't get where my bottlenecks are because (a) I use `data.frame` pretty often and (b) I never use e.g., `deparse`. Furthermore, what is `[`?

So I tried Hadley Wickham's `profr`, but it was not any more useful considering the following graph:
[image]

**Is there a more convenient way to see which line numbers and particular function calls are slow?

Or, is there some literature that I should consult?**

Any hints appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Based on Hadley's comment I will paste the code of my script below and the base graph version of the plot. But note, that my question is not related to this specific script. It is just a random script that I recently wrote. **I am looking for a general way of how to find bottlenecks and speed up `R`-code.**

The data (`x`) looks like this:

> ```
> type      word    response    N   Classification  classN
> Abstract  ANGER   bitter      1   3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   control     1   1a              1a
> Abstract  ANGER   father      1   3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   flushed     1   3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   fury        1   1c              1c
> Abstract  ANGER   hat         1   3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   help        1   3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   mad         13  3a              3a
> Abstract  ANGER   management  2   1a              1a
> ... until row 1700
> ```

The script (with short explanations) is this:

> ```
> Rprof("profile1.out")
>
> # A new dataset is produced with each line of x contained x$N times 
> y <- vector('list',length(x[,1]))
> for (i in 1:length(x[,1])) {
>   y[[i]] <- data.frame(rep(x[i,1],x[i,"N"]),rep(x[i,2],x[i,"N"]),rep(x[i,3],x[i,"N"]),rep(x[i,4],x[i,"N"]),rep(x[i,5],x[i,"N"]),rep(x[i,6],x[i,"N"]))
> }
> all <- do.call('rbind',y)
> colnames(all) <- colnames(x)
>
> # create a dataframe out of a word x class table
> table_all <- table(all$word,all$classN)
> dataf.all <- as.data.frame(table_all[,1:length(table_all[1,])])
> dataf.all$words <- as.factor(rownames(dataf.all))
> dataf.all$type <- "no"
> # get type of the word.
> words <- levels(dataf.all$words)
> for (i in 1:length(words)) {
>   dataf.all$type[i] <- as.character(all[pmatch(words[i],all$word),"type"])
> }
> dataf.all$type <- as.factor(dataf.all$type)
> dataf.all$typeN <- as.numeric(dataf.all$type)
>
> # aggregate response categories
> dataf.all$c1 <- apply(dataf.all[,c("1a","1b","1c","1d","1e","1f")],1,sum)
> dataf.all$c2 <- apply(dataf.all[,c("2a","2b","2c")],1,sum)
> dataf.all$c3 <- apply(dataf.all[,c("3a","3b")],1,sum)
>
> Rprof(NULL)
>
> library(profr)
> ggplot.profr(parse_rprof("profile1.out"))
> ```

Final data looks like this:

> ```
> 1a    1b  1c  1d  1e  1f  2a  2b  2c  3a  3b  pa  words   type    typeN   c1  c2  c3  pa
> 3 0   8   0   0   0   0   0   0   24  0   0   ANGER   Abstract    1   11  0   24  0
> 6 0   4   0   1   0   0   11  0   13  0   0   ANXIETY Abstract    1   11  11  13  0
> 2 11  1   0   0   0   0   4   0   17  0   0   ATTITUDE    Abstract    1   14  4   17  0
> 9 18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8   0   BARREL  Concrete    2   27  0   8   0
> 0 1   18  0   0   0   0   4   0   12  0   0   BELIEF  Abstract    1   19  4   12  0
> ```

The base graph plot:
[image]

[Running the script today also changed the ggplot2 graph a little (basically only the labels), see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRq5L.png)

Comment: Can you try using `plot` instead of `ggplot` with profr?  It would also be useful to see your original code.

Comment: I get so tired of pointing this out. Profilers based on the same ideas as in **gprof** have the same faults. All this business about self time, functions instead of lines, graphs, and measurement in general, are just the same warmed-over useless concepts. There are easy ways around it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: @hadely: see my edit.  @Mike: I get that finding the problem and not measuring sth. basically unrelated is your point. It sound exactly like what I am looking for. But is this implemented in R somewhere?

Comment: @Henrik: Somebody just gave me a vote and brought my attention back here. In fact I've used Rprof, but only to take samples (at large intervals), not to "analyze" them. The samples end up in a file, and I just look at them. Although they don't contain line-number information, they work. If function A calls function B in two places, I instead have A call B1 and B2, and those guys call B. That way I can tell where in A the calls come from. Kludgy, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Alert readers of yesterdays [breaking news](http://cran.r-project.org/src/base/NEWS.html) (`R 3.0.0` is finally out) may have noticed something interesting that is directly relevant to this question:

> - Profiling via Rprof() now optionally records information at the statement level, not just the function level.

And indeed, this new feature answers my question and I will show how.

---

Let's say, we want to compare whether vectorizing and pre-allocating are really better than good old for-loops and incremental building of data in calculating a summary statistic such as the mean. The, relatively stupid, code is the following:

```
# create big data frame:
n <- 1000
x <- data.frame(group = sample(letters[1:4], n, replace=TRUE), condition = sample(LETTERS[1:10], n, replace = TRUE), data = rnorm(n))

# reasonable operations:
marginal.means.1 <- aggregate(data ~ group + condition, data = x, FUN=mean)

# unreasonable operations:
marginal.means.2 <- marginal.means.1[NULL,]

row.counter <- 1
for (condition in levels(x$condition)) {
  for (group in levels(x$group)) {  
    tmp.value <- 0
    tmp.length <- 0
    for (c in 1:nrow(x)) {
      if ((x[c,"group"] == group) & (x[c,"condition"] == condition)) {
        tmp.value <- tmp.value + x[c,"data"]
        tmp.length <- tmp.length + 1
      }
    }
    marginal.means.2[row.counter,"group"] <- group 
    marginal.means.2[row.counter,"condition"] <- condition
    marginal.means.2[row.counter,"data"] <- tmp.value / tmp.length
    row.counter <- row.counter + 1
  }
}

# does it produce the same results?
all.equal(marginal.means.1, marginal.means.2)
```

To use this code with `Rprof`, we need to `parse` it. That is, it needs to be saved in a file and then called from there. Hence, I uploaded it to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KjdkSVZq), but it works exactly the same with local files.

Now, we

- simply create a profile file and indicate that we want to save the line number,
- source the code with the incredible combination `eval(parse(..., keep.source = TRUE))` (seemingly the infamous `fortune(106)` does not apply here, as I haven't found another way)
- stop the profiling and indicate that we want the output based on the line numbers.

The code is:

```
Rprof("profile1.out", line.profiling=TRUE)
eval(parse(file = "http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=KjdkSVZq", keep.source=TRUE))
Rprof(NULL)

summaryRprof("profile1.out", lines = "show")
```

Which gives:

```
$by.self
                           self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#17      8.04    64.11       8.04     64.11
<no location>                   4.38    34.93       4.38     34.93
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#16      0.06     0.48       0.06      0.48
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#18      0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#23      0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#6       0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16

$by.total
                           total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#17       8.04     64.11      8.04    64.11
<no location>                    4.38     34.93      4.38    34.93
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#16       0.06      0.48      0.06     0.48
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#18       0.02      0.16      0.02     0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#23       0.02      0.16      0.02     0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#6        0.02      0.16      0.02     0.16

$by.line
                           self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
<no location>                   4.38    34.93       4.38     34.93
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#6       0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#16      0.06     0.48       0.06      0.48
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#17      8.04    64.11       8.04     64.11
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#18      0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16
download.php?i=KjdkSVZq#23      0.02     0.16       0.02      0.16

$sample.interval
[1] 0.02

$sampling.time
[1] 12.54
```

Checking the [source code](http://pastebin.com/KjdkSVZq) tells us that the problematic line (#17) is indeed the stupid `if`-statement in the for-loop. Compared with basically no time for calculating the same using vectorized code (line #6).

I haven't tried it with any graphical output, but I am already very impressed by what I got so far.

Comment: Why not `source("http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=KjdkSVZq")` instead of `eval(parse(..., keep.source = TRUE))`?

Comment: Can it tell, by source line, what fraction of the time that line was on the stack? Is that what "total.pct" is?

Comment: Is the parsing necessary? Can't I just give the R experssions directly between the Rprof lines?

Comment: @Avinash No, see comment by flodel above. You can simply source it. If other versions also work, you need to try out on your own.

Comment: My solution to a similar question (I found this question after posting mine), may be helpful as well: [How does one interpret the output from profr::profr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637159/how-does-one-interpret-the-output-from-profrprofr)

Comment: @Alex Why don't you post your solution here? Your question is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: @Henrik they're slightly different questions. This one is on `base::Rprof`, mine is on `profr::profr` ... but I can post my solution here if you would like.

Comment: @Alex Yes. In the end the question is about how to efficiently profile in R. Your answer is relevant and this questions draws considerable attention. I will upvote your answer here.

Answer (score 11):

**Update:** This function has been re-written to deal with line numbers.  It's on github [here](https://github.com/noamross/noamtools/blob/master/R/proftable.R).

I wrote this function to parse the file from `Rprof` and output a table of somewhat clearer results than `summaryRprof`.  It displays the full stack of functions (and line numbers if `line.profiling=TRUE`), and their relative contribution to run time:

```
proftable <- function(file, lines=10) {
# require(plyr)
  interval <- as.numeric(strsplit(readLines(file, 1), "=")[[1L]][2L])/1e+06
  profdata <- read.table(file, header=FALSE, sep=" ", comment.char = "",
                         colClasses="character", skip=1, fill=TRUE,
                         na.strings="")
  filelines <- grep("#File", profdata[,1])
  files <- aaply(as.matrix(profdata[filelines,]), 1, function(x) {
                        paste(na.omit(x), collapse = " ") })
  profdata <- profdata[-filelines,]
  total.time <- interval*nrow(profdata)
  profdata <- as.matrix(profdata[,ncol(profdata):1])
  profdata <- aaply(profdata, 1, function(x) {
                      c(x[(sum(is.na(x))+1):length(x)],
                        x[seq(from=1,by=1,length=sum(is.na(x)))])
              })
  stringtable <- table(apply(profdata, 1, paste, collapse=" "))
  uniquerows <- strsplit(names(stringtable), " ")
  uniquerows <- llply(uniquerows, function(x) replace(x, which(x=="NA"), NA))
  dimnames(stringtable) <- NULL
  stacktable <- ldply(uniquerows, function(x) x)
  stringtable <- stringtable/sum(stringtable)*100
  stacktable <- data.frame(PctTime=stringtable[], stacktable)
  stacktable <- stacktable[order(stringtable, decreasing=TRUE),]
  rownames(stacktable) <- NULL
  stacktable <- head(stacktable, lines)
  na.cols <- which(sapply(stacktable, function(x) all(is.na(x))))
  stacktable <- stacktable[-na.cols]
  parent.cols <- which(sapply(stacktable, function(x) length(unique(x)))==1)
  parent.call <- paste0(paste(stacktable[1,parent.cols], collapse = " > ")," >")
  stacktable <- stacktable[,-parent.cols]
  calls <- aaply(as.matrix(stacktable[2:ncol(stacktable)]), 1, function(x) {
                   paste(na.omit(x), collapse= " > ")
                     })
  stacktable <- data.frame(PctTime=stacktable$PctTime, Call=calls)
  frac <- sum(stacktable$PctTime)
  attr(stacktable, "total.time") <- total.time
  attr(stacktable, "parent.call") <- parent.call
  attr(stacktable, "files") <- files
  attr(stacktable, "total.pct.time") <- frac
  cat("\n")
  print(stacktable, row.names=FALSE, right=FALSE, digits=3)
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste(files, collapse="\n"))
  cat("\n")
  cat(paste("\nParent Call:", parent.call))
  cat(paste("\n\nTotal Time:", total.time, "seconds\n"))
  cat(paste0("Percent of run time represented: ", format(frac, digits=3)), "%")

  invisible(stacktable)
}
```

Running this on the Henrik's example file, I get this:

```
> Rprof("profile1.out", line.profiling=TRUE)
> source("http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=KjdkSVZq")
> Rprof(NULL)
> proftable("profile1.out", lines=10)

 PctTime Call                                                      
 20.47   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame                            
  9.73   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame > [ > [.factor             
  8.72   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame > [ > [.factor > NextMethod
  8.39   == > Ops.factor                                           
  5.37   ==                                                        
  5.03   == > Ops.factor > noNA.levels > levels                    
  4.70   == > Ops.factor > NextMethod                              
  4.03   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame > [ > [.factor > levels    
  4.03   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame > dim                      
  3.36   1#17 > [ > 1#17 > [.data.frame > length                   

#File 1: http://pastebin.com/download.php?i=KjdkSVZq

Parent Call: source > withVisible > eval > eval >

Total Time: 5.96 seconds
Percent of run time represented: 73.8 %
```

Note that the "Parent Call" applies to all the stacks represented on the table.  This makes is useful when your IDE or whatever calls your code wraps it in a bunch of functions.

Comment: Looks nice. But is there any chance to also obtain the information in which line we are (i.e., from which line the stack was called)?

Comment: That is some good news. You should be aware, that there is still a [bug in the current implementation](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-April/350964.html) (but possibly not in R devel).

Comment: I've rewritten the function to deal with line numbers, and also to improve readability for long stacks.  Get the code here: https://github.com/noamross/noamtools/blob/master/R/proftable.R

Comment: + @Noam: Just saw your answer. I've also used `rprof`, but I don't post-process, I just look at a random selection of the raw stack samples. My version didn't have line numbers in the stack samples (or maybe it could have and I didn't realize it). Anyway, it got the job done.

Comment: There's a spelling mistake: 'aaply' - can't edit it just for that, but it makes it not work on copy-paste - would be good to fix it.

Comment: @naught101 It's not an error.  It's actually plyr::aaply. You can uncomment `require(plyr)` at the top of the function, or install the package which includes this at http://github.com/noamross/noamtools

Answer (score 3):

I currently have R uninstalled here, but in SPlus you can interrupt the execution with the Escape key, and then do `traceback()`, which will show you the call stack. That should enable you to use [*this handy method*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

[*Here are some reasons why*](http://archive.today/9r927) tools built on the same concepts as **gprof** are not very good at locating performance problems.

Comment: Looks like that question was deleted. Do you know of any other source of information on that topic (ways around these "warmed-over useless concepts", as you say in your comment above)?

Comment: @naught101: That post isn't gone, you just need enough rep. I'm the main flamer on this subject, and I'm really trying not to be. The other link here, "this handy method" spells it out without flaming too much. In a nutshell, no profiler can analyze a stack sample anywhere near as well as a human can, any bottleneck worth fixing can be found quickly, and fixing each bottleneck makes others easier to find, so you can keep rolling. "CPU profiling" misses IO. Recursion is not an issue. Accuracy of measurement is not important, nor is "self time", nor call counts, etc. etc.

Comment: Hrm. Sounds useful, but I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to profiling and related activities. It'd be great if someone with R isntalled could translate this answer into a method that I can use in R.

Comment: @naught101: Run `rprof` (you might have to rummage a bit for the doc). When I run it, I set the sample rate very low, so I don't get scads of samples. It generates a text file of stack samples. All I do is look at that. If you see it doing something on 5 out of 10 stack samples, that means if you could speed up what you see it doing, you could potentially save around 50% of time, give or take. That's a big saving.

Comment: The post isn't gone: https://web.archive.org/web/20130817143313/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343

Answer (score 3):

A different solution comes from a different question: [how to effectively use `library(profr)` in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32637159/how-does-one-interpret-the-output-from-profrprofr):

For example:

```
install.packages("profr")
devtools::install_github("alexwhitworth/imputation")

x <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100)
x[x>1] <- NA
library(imputation)
library(profr)
a <- profr(kNN_impute(x, k=5, q=2), interval= 0.005)
```

It doesn't seem (to me at least), like the plots are at all helpful here (eg `plot(a)`). But the data structure itself does seem to suggest a solution:

```
R> head(a, 10)
   level g_id t_id                f start   end n  leaf  time     source
9      1    1    1       kNN_impute 0.005 0.190 1 FALSE 0.185 imputation
10     2    1    1        var_tests 0.005 0.010 1 FALSE 0.005       <NA>
11     2    2    1            apply 0.010 0.190 1 FALSE 0.180       base
12     3    1    1         var.test 0.005 0.010 1 FALSE 0.005      stats
13     3    2    1              FUN 0.010 0.110 1 FALSE 0.100       <NA>
14     3    2    2              FUN 0.115 0.190 1 FALSE 0.075       <NA>
15     4    1    1 var.test.default 0.005 0.010 1 FALSE 0.005       <NA>
16     4    2    1           sapply 0.010 0.040 1 FALSE 0.030       base
17     4    3    1    dist_q.matrix 0.040 0.045 1 FALSE 0.005 imputation
18     4    4    1           sapply 0.045 0.075 1 FALSE 0.030       base
```

#### Single iteration solution:

That is the data structure suggests the use of `tapply` to summarize the data. This can be done quite simply for a single run of `profr::profr`

```
t <- tapply(a$time, paste(a$source, a$f, sep= "::"), sum)
t[order(t)] # time / function
R> round(t[order(t)] / sum(t), 4) # percentage of total time / function

base::!                    base::%in%                       base::|           base::anyDuplicated 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
                      base::c                 base::deparse                     base::get                   base::match 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
                   base::mget                     base::min                       base::t                   methods::el 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
          methods::getGeneric        NA::.findMethodInTable               NA::.getGeneric      NA::.getGenericFromCache 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
NA::.getGenericFromCacheTable                   NA::.identC             NA::.newSignature        NA::.quickCoerceSelect 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
                NA::.sigLabel          NA::var.test.default                 NA::var_tests               stats::var.test 
                       0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015                        0.0015 
                  base::paste                 methods::as<-     NA::.findInheritedMethods        NA::.getClassFromCache 
                       0.0030                        0.0030                        0.0030                        0.0030 
               NA::doTryCatch              NA::tryCatchList               NA::tryCatchOne               base::crossprod 
                       0.0030                        0.0030                        0.0030                        0.0045 
                    base::try                base::tryCatch          methods::getClassDef      methods::possibleExtends 
                       0.0045                        0.0045                        0.0045                        0.0045 
          methods::loadMethod                   methods::is     imputation::dist_q.matrix          methods::validObject 
                       0.0075                        0.0090                        0.0120                        0.0136 
       NA::.findNextFromTable        methods::addNextMethod               NA::.nextMethod                  base::lapply 
                       0.0166                        0.0346                        0.0361                        0.0392 
                 base::sapply     imputation::impute_fn_knn                  methods::new        imputation::kNN_impute 
                       0.0392                        0.0392                        0.0437                        0.0557 
      methods::callNextMethod      kernlab::as.kernelMatrix                   base::apply         kernlab::kernelMatrix 
                       0.0572                        0.0633                        0.0663                        0.0753 
          methods::initialize                       NA::FUN         base::standardGeneric 
                       0.0798                        0.0994                        0.1325
```

From this, I can see that the biggest time users are `kernlab::kernelMatrix` and the overhead from **R** for S4 classes and generics.

#### Preferred:

I note that, given the stochastic nature of the sampling process, I prefer to use averages to get a more robust picture of the time profile:

```
prof_list <- replicate(100, profr(kNN_impute(x, k=5, q=2), 
    interval= 0.005), simplify = FALSE)

fun_timing <- vector("list", length= 100)
for (i in 1:100) {
  fun_timing[[i]] <- tapply(prof_list[[i]]$time, paste(prof_list[[i]]$source, prof_list[[i]]$f, sep= "::"), sum)
}

# Here is where the stochastic nature of the profiler complicates things.
# Because of randomness, each replication may have slightly different 
# functions called during profiling
sapply(fun_timing, function(x) {length(names(x))})

# we can also see some clearly odd replications (at least in my attempt)
> sapply(fun_timing, sum)
[1]    2.820    5.605    2.325    2.895    3.195    2.695    2.495    2.315    2.005    2.475    4.110    2.705    2.180    2.760
 [15] 3130.240    3.435    7.675    7.155    5.205    3.760    7.335    7.545    8.155    8.175    6.965    5.820    8.760    7.345
 [29]    9.815    7.965    6.370    4.900    5.720    4.530    6.220    3.345    4.055    3.170    3.725    7.780    7.090    7.670
 [43]    5.400    7.635    7.125    6.905    6.545    6.855    7.185    7.610    2.965    3.865    3.875    3.480    7.770    7.055
 [57]    8.870    8.940   10.130    9.730    5.205    5.645    3.045    2.535    2.675    2.695    2.730    2.555    2.675    2.270
 [71]    9.515    4.700    7.270    2.950    6.630    8.370    9.070    7.950    3.250    4.405    3.475    6.420 2948.265    3.470
 [85]    3.320    3.640    2.855    3.315    2.560    2.355    2.300    2.685    2.855    2.540    2.480    2.570    3.345    2.145
 [99]    2.620    3.650
```

Removing the unusual replications and converting to `data.frame`s:

```
fun_timing <- fun_timing[-c(15,83)]
fun_timing2 <- lapply(fun_timing, function(x) {
  ret <- data.frame(fun= names(x), time= x)
  dimnames(ret)[[1]] <- 1:nrow(ret)
  return(ret)
})
```

Merge replications (almost certainly could be faster) and examine results:

```
# function for merging DF's in a list
merge_recursive <- function(list, ...) {
  n <- length(list)
  df <- data.frame(list[[1]])
  for (i in 2:n) {
    df <- merge(df, list[[i]], ... = ...)
  }
  return(df)
}

# merge
fun_time <- merge_recursive(fun_timing2, by= "fun", all= FALSE)
# do some munging
fun_time2 <- data.frame(fun=fun_time[,1], avg_time=apply(fun_time[,-1], 1, mean, na.rm=T))
fun_time2$avg_pct <- fun_time2$avg_time / sum(fun_time2$avg_time)
fun_time2 <- fun_time2[order(fun_time2$avg_time, decreasing=TRUE),]
# examine results
R> head(fun_time2, 15)
                         fun  avg_time    avg_pct
4      base::standardGeneric 0.6760714 0.14745123
20                   NA::FUN 0.4666327 0.10177262
12       methods::initialize 0.4488776 0.09790023
9      kernlab::kernelMatrix 0.3522449 0.07682464
8   kernlab::as.kernelMatrix 0.3215816 0.07013698
11   methods::callNextMethod 0.2986224 0.06512958
1                base::apply 0.2893367 0.06310437
7     imputation::kNN_impute 0.2433163 0.05306731
14              methods::new 0.2309184 0.05036331
10    methods::addNextMethod 0.2012245 0.04388708
3               base::sapply 0.1875000 0.04089377
2               base::lapply 0.1865306 0.04068234
6  imputation::impute_fn_knn 0.1827551 0.03985890
19           NA::.nextMethod 0.1790816 0.03905772
18    NA::.findNextFromTable 0.1003571 0.02188790
```

#### Results

From the results, a similar but more robust picture emerges as with a single case. Namely, there is a lot of overhead from **R** and also that `library(kernlab)` is slowing me down. Of note, since `kernlab` is implemented in S4, the overhead in **R** is related since S4 classes are substantially slower than S3 classes.

I'd also note that my personal opinion is that a cleaned up version of this might be a useful pull request as a summary method for [profr](https://github.com/hadley/profr). Although I'd be interested to see others' suggestions!