# Confused About Rprof with R

Tags: r

I'm confused as to how to get `Rprof` to work with R.

I followed the sample in the documentation and had something like

```
Rprof(filename="testProfile.out")
test()
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("testProfile.out")
```

However, inside `testProfile.out`, I had one line : `sample.interval=20000`

This confuses me and when I run `summaryRProf`, I get `no events were recorded`

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does test() do? Rprof profiles working code. So if test() returns an error that the function test() could not be found, there are no events to be recorded.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15821706/289572

Comment: Mmm.. lets say that test = function() {
  for (i in 1:50) print(i)
}

Comment: as an example that produces the issue above

Comment: change `1:50` to `1:5000` and you'll start seeing stuff. As is, your `test()` is just too fast for the default `interval = 0.02`. You could also just try to profile `for (i in 1:100) test()`.

Comment: Hi Flodel, that indeed fixed it. If you answer the question I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that my test was completing too quickly and Rprof was not logging at fast enough intervals. To fix, this you can either set `interval = 0.0002` or some number smaller than the default value (`0.02`). I was also able to fix this by running my test for multiple iterations.