# Command on a subset of a data.table: equivalent formulations

Tags: r, data.table

These three commands return the same result (regression on a subset of observations). I'd like to know whether there are important differences in term of what data.table really does in the background.

```
suppressMessages(library("data.table"))
suppressMessages(library("biglm"))
N=1e7; K=100
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(
  id = 1:N,
  v1 =  sample(5, N, TRUE),                          # int in range [1,5]
  v2 =  sample(1e6, N, TRUE),                        # int in range [1,1e6]
  v3 =  sample(round(runif(100,max=100),4), N, TRUE) # numeric e.g. 23.5749
)
DT[, condition := id>100]

# fist command
coefficients(biglm(v3 ~ v2 + v1, DT[id>100, c("v1", "v2", "v3"), with = FALSE]))

# second command
DT[ id >100, coefficients(biglm(v3 ~ v2 + v1, .SD)), .SDcols = c("v1", "v2", "v3")]

# third command
DT[, coefficients(biglm(v3 ~ v2 + v1, .SD)), by = condition, .SDcols = c("v1", "v2", "v3")]
```

If I run each command in a new session of R, it seems that the time taken by each command is the same. In a more general situation, are all these commands equivalent from a memory / speed point of view? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment....

#### first command

- Creates an explicit temporary copy of DT where id>100
- Does not appear to create coefficients for id<=100
- creates a length N logical vector and uses a vector scan to subset

#### Second command

- creates an implicit copy of of DT where id>100
- creates a length N logical vector and uses a vector scan to subset
- Does not appear to create coefficients for id<=100

#### Third command

- creates an implicit copes of of DT where id>100 and id <=100 (only using the memory for the larger)
- creates two sets of coefficients.

From a speed point of view, I would think that the processing of `biglm` would be slow point (relative to any use of data.table).

You might get a speed up by setting the key by `condition` (however this will take time). If you need to use this condition generally for subsetting this would appear to be useful.

eg.

```
setkey(DT, condition)
```

You can then use a binary search to extract data by the condition

```
DT[.(TRUE)]
DT[.(FALSE)]
```

These will be faster, and more memory efficient.

It might be worth investigating processing subsets of the data using `update` to add them to the biglm. Look at using `profr` or `utils::Rprof` (see [How to efficiently use Rprof in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650862/how-to-efficiently-use-rprof-in-r)) and the documenation.